# How to config android studio avd path?

Tags: android, android-studio

Today I use `google android studio ide` to make some test, when I create a new avd, I find the avd is generated at the path `C:\Users\username\\.android\avd`. I don't want that.

Anyone tell me how to config avd to another path?

Answer (score 2):

You can read the topic http://wloescher.blogspot.com/2011/01/android-hello-world-tale-of-woe.html

1. custom ANDROID_SDK_HOME
2. use -p paramter

Comment: well, I get it. Just move the avd4.2.avd('C:\Users\username\.android\avd\avd4.2.avd') to another path( mine is 'D:\androidavd\avd4.2.avd'), then edit avd4.2.ini, change path value to 'D:\androidavd\avd4.2.avd'. It works!!