# Creating an Android AVD in a specific path

Tags: windows, android-studio-3.0, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I noticed that AVD MAnager creates all AVD machines in the folder Users of disk C.

Well... I have got SSD 120 GB and it is full... So I would like to create all AVDs in disk D.

How to configure Android Studio to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703821/how-to-config-android-studio-avd-path